# Jquery ChildElementCount

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the jquery ajax xml 101 question ...

I have 2 questions:
1) Counting the child nodes inside the `<RESULTS>`. In this case there's only element happens to be called OBS. I want to know the jquery method for doing this. I have it with long hand javascript.
2) Can you advise the preferred method for accessing these counts (read down).

XML file looks like this...

```
<TABLE>
 <RESULTS>
  <OBS>..</OBS>
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
  <OBS>..</OBS>
 </RESULTS>
</TABLE>
```

There are 2 `<RESULTS>` and 1 child `<OBS>` returned.
I've got that covered with ...

Long hand Javascript:

```
var items = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('RESULTS');
console.log("child Element Count= ",items[0].childElementCount); // will return 1 = OBS
console.log("nodes Count= ",items.length); // will return 2 =RESULTS
```

So we're good with that but with jquery.

Short hand Jquery:

```
var count=$(result).find("RESULTS").size();         
var countLength=$(result).find("RESULTS").length;
```

Both will return "2".
How do I get to the count of the child elements? In this case the answer would be 1 as there's just `<OBS>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(result).find("RESULTS").length` counts the number of `<RESULTS>` elements. You're looking for the number of child elements in the first `<RESULTS>` element:

```
var count = $(result).find('RESULTS').first().children().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this instead

```
$("RESULTS:first-child").children().length
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'll show a couple of examples that may get you going:

```
// original XML string
var xml = '<TABLE><RESULTS><OBS>..</OBS></RESULTS><RESULTS><OBS>..</OBS></RESULTS></TABLE>';
// XMl -> jQuery object
var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

// Total item counts
var numberOfResults = $xml.find('RESULTS').size();
    console.log(numberOfResults); // output: 2
var numberOfObs = $xml.find('RESULTS>OBS').size();
    console.log(numberOfObs); // output: 2

// item count specific to the first <RESULTS> node:
var $firstResultsNode = $xml.find('RESULTS').first();
var numberOfObs = $firstResultsNode.children('OBS').size();
    console.log(numberOfObs); // output: 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning. The reality of the situation is that the Ajax call will return either one row with one node (if no rows in the query) or 1 or more rows with loads of nodes if it's a good query. As a good response can potentially produce one row as well as a bad response then I think the easiest method of handling this (as I want to output different things based on whether it's a good or bad response) is to search for a specific element <response> and see if the value = "No Response"  and if so, then do "this" else do "that". The syntax above did confirm a few things for me though.