# Why childElementCount not work with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use childElementCount with jQuery so is there any way to check this ?

Here is code of working javascript :

```
var box = document.getElementById('list_items').childElementCount;

alert(box);
```

But why this is not working with jQuery.

```
var box = $('list_items').childElementCount;
```

I found stackoverflow post here :

Visit : [Jquery ChildElementCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032692/jquery-childelementcount)

But it's showing :

```
var count = $(result).find('RESULTS').first().children().length;
```

And maybe rather then using this code javascript is good way but there is other DOM Properties also that i want to use with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery collections do not have the properties of the DOM nodes they contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling a DOM property on a jQuery object. You must get the DOM element which is embedded in the jQuery object :

```
var box = $('#list_items').get(0).childElementCount;
```

Comment: WOW! So fast... can with .get(0) can i access other properties ?

Comment: .get(0) gives you a DOM element. You can use all the properties DOM elements normally have

Answer (score 2):

it is a property of dom element, also you need to use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for the `list_items` element

```
var box = $('#list_items').prop('childElementCount');
```

`$('#list_items')` returns a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) which does not have the `childElementCount` property, it belongs to the dom element so you need to get the property value of the underlying dom element, you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to do that

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `#` before the id selector. Then `childElementCount` is the property of dom element so convert jQuery object into dom object

```
var box = $('#list_items')[0].childElementCount;
```

`$('#list_items')` returns a jQuery object, `$('#list_items')[0]` returns the dom object